# How do I select records and summary in one query?

Tags: linq

The scenario is like this:

```
name | val  
'aa' | 10
'bb' | 20
'cc' | 30
*********
sum  | 60
```

For now I just select all the records in simple LINQ query and invoke the enumerator (`ToList()`)

Then I loop over the list and summarize the `val` column.

Is there a better way? LINQ selects all to a new typed object so I dont know how to add the additional data.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous type cant allow value to be added or edited once its created. so instead of returning anonymous type, you can use your custom output class. Something like this

```
        public class ResClass
        {
            public string name;
            public int value;
        }

        public class OutClass
        {
             public int sum;
             public List<ResClass> lstData;
        }

        int sum=0;
        var outtt = objTT.Where(x => x.id == 1).Select(x =>
        {
            sum += x.value;
            return new ResClass { name =  x.name, value= x.value };

        }).ToList();

        OutClass outCls = new OutClass { sum = sum, lstData = outtt };
```

Comment: thanks for the replay.
the "sum += x.value;" is new way for me. is there is some way to
do this with from x in y select.. style?

Comment: @ari, "sum += x.value" is nothing but "sum=sum+x.value", which means it adds up the x.value on each iteration to calculate the sum..

Comment: i dont think we cant do that in "from x in y style", well i am not sure.. since am using anonymous methods, its the way to do that... well atleast

Comment: yes i familier with += approuch.
the option to include "out of context" command in the select
is new for me. i'am always working with "from x in y style"..